# How can I define a RAML spec for a POST method taking an array of string as parameters

Tags: web-services, rest, post, parameters, raml

I am trying to publish a RAML for a post method of a restful web service which takes an array of strings.  Basically , I want to have one parameter called colour which and I want to be able to pass in multiple values such as:

colour: {blue, red, white}.  So i want one parameter but multiple values.

I am not sure how to publish the RAML for that though I did consult the RAML tutorials.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RAML 1 you can do this:

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: test
types:
  colour: string[]
/test:
  post:
    body:
      application/json:
        type: colour
```